# Installing .ipa on iPhone

Tags: ios11

I received **.ipa** file from my developer. I installed it through iTunes and it was working fine. After I upgraded my phone to iOS 11, the App is asking for update by developer.

1. How my developer can update it?
2. iTunes 12 does not have Apps tab, how I can install a new .ipa by iTunes?

Answer (score 2):

For your first point, if the app no longer works in iOS11 this could be caused by a number of issues. Most commonly, the issue would be that the app is not built for 64bit architecture. However this is something the dev would need to look at.

For you second point, it is iTunes 12.7 that has removed the applications option. Doing a little of my own research I think the current best solution (although I have not tried this myself yet) is to download iTunes 12.6.3 where the applications option is still available.

Please see the following link for a guide on how to do this: https://www.macworld.com/article/3230135/software-entertainment/how-to-install-itunes-1263-and-replace-itunes-127.html

The only downside I can see is that it is no longer in support as Apple only provide support for the latest version of iTunes (12.7 at the time of writing). However I guess that's exactly what stack overflow is for!

Let me know how it goes!